# Empty list of services when printing client with SUDS and python

Tags: python, django, soap, suds

I don't get any information of my SOAP client when I print it with SUDS.

**Code:**

```
url = 'https://website.com/API/AuthenticationService.asmx'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'}
client = Client(url, headers = headers)
print client
```

**Print result:**

```
Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.6
```

**I should be able to pass username and password with XML:**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<Login xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://Iris.net">
<username>Username</username>
<password>Password</password>
</Login>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

If I try to use any service or factory namespaces, I get an error.

**With trying to use service:**

```
response = client.service.Login(username)
```

**Error:**

```
Exception: No services defined
```

**And with factory:**

```
    login = client.factory.create('Login')
```

**Error:**

```
Exception: (Login, None, ), must be qref
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the web service can't use suds, so I found it work with xml request. Found correct answer here: [Python: Making a request with suds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20448276/python-making-a-request-with-suds)